# cakePHP isUnique is not working any more

Tags: cakephp

I had this validation rule for a long time and it always used to work correctly, but not any more.

```
  public $validate = array(
            'email'=>array(
                'email'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('email', true),
                    'message'=>'E-mail is not correct'
                ),
                'isUnique'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'isUnique',
                    'message'=>'This email adddress is already in use'
                ),
                'notEmpty'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message'=>'Insert email address'
                )
            )
```

I have been testing many possible ways, but none of them seem to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the add function from the controller:

public function add() {

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

if( $this->request->data[ 'User' ][ 'email' ] != $this->data[ 'User' ][ 'email_confirmation' ] ) {
    $this->User->invalidate( 'email_confirmation', __('Emails dont match'));
}else{

//generate password

$generatedPassword = $this->getRandomString(6);

$this->request->data['User']['password'] = $generatedPassword;


if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

    $name = $this->request->data['User']['name'];
    $email = $this->request->data['User']['email'];
    $password = $generatedPassword;


        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User has been saved'), 'positive_notification');

        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User has not been saved'), 'negative_notification');
    }
    }}}
```

And here is the beforeSave()

```
public function beforeSave($options = Array()){
    if(isset($this->data['User']['password'])){
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password1'])){
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password1']);
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Here is the query that is being executed while saving:

```
INSERT INTO `schedule`.`users` (`employee_nr`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `phone`, `address`, `post_nr`, `city`, `role`, `company_id`, `password`) VALUES ('1', 'Name', 'Surname', 'email@email.com', '11223344', '', '', '', 'employee', 54, '389be16c83bf2e65a64f727465ec0c37a77552a5')
```

Comment: I have tried both create and update, and the isUnique rule is just not being checked on email field. Even though all of the other rules work perfectly well.

Comment: Is there is anything on your `beforeValidate()`?

Comment: The question has just been updated with all the necessary information

Comment: Are you writing in invisible ink =)? There's no query log (which is probably the more important bit of info), and .. you do not indicate what `$this->request->data` is when it "doesn't work" or what "doesn't work" actually means. One thing unrelated to your immediate question - you are going to be rehashing the user's password if it is in any other save operations.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. The query from saving a user, has been added.

Comment: But that is the whole log that I can see. The find is not even happening, that is why the question was rised in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't seem likely that the _only_ query your request executes is one insert statement. If that's all the log you can see - where are you looking? If the only validation rule that "doesn't work" is isUnique - then it sounds likely your model or app model has overridden [the isUnique function](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3256). If no validation rules work, it sounds likely the model file is misnamed. Anyway: Good luck =).

Answer (score 1):

Test [isUnique](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_isUnique) by using in you controller to see why it is not working. `isUnique` validation rule uses `isUnique` model method.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  public $validate = array(                
      'email' => array(
        'rule1' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address.'
        ),
        'rule2' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'That email address exists.'
        )
    ),
```